# Capturing access token from an API redirect URL

Tags: python, python-3.x, api, oauth, python-requests

I am trying to capture my access token that is returned by an API during authentication process. The official method of doing the authentication process from the API is:

```
from xyz_api import accessToken
app_id = "your_app_id"
app_secret = "your_app_secret"
app_session = accessToken.SessionModel(app_id, app_secret)
response = app_session.auth()
```

The above will return a json like:

```
{

"code" : 200,

"data" : {

"authorization_code": "some random code"

},
}
```

Now, the following code is used to generate a URL:

```
authorization_code = “your_authorization_code”

app_session.set_token(authorization_code)

url = app_session.generate_token()
```

> Now this is where I start having issue.

At this stage, what is recommended by the API author is:

```
1. Use the generated URL and copy paste it into a browser. 
2. The browser will then do the authentication and return the access token to a redirect 
url (I used http://localhost:5000).
3. Copy and paste the access token from redirect URL
```

**What I want:**

```
To be able to finish the authentication and get the access_token from
python code itself.
```

**What I tried:**
Using requests.get(url), but it doesn't work.

Is there any way to do this all using *python only, without having a need to open a browser*?

```
PS: The API I am trying to use is: https://api-docs.fyers.in/v1#authorization
```

**Further Investigation**

On further investigation, I discovered the following:

1. The API uses oauth
2. The URL obtained from the following code provided by the API author

   url = app_session.generate_token()

is same as when I write the following code:

```
oauth = OAuth2Session('app_id')
authorization_url, state = oauth.authorization_url(url)
```

3. The url returned in both cases is of the form:

   https://api.fyers.in/api/v1/genrateToken?authorization_code=some_auth_code&appId=my_app_id
4. If I copy paste this URL in a browser, it send back the access_token to my redirect_url (http://localhost:5000)
5. I am trying to get the access token using oauth::fetch_token with the following code, which is failing:

   oauth1 = OAuth2Session('app_id', state=state, redirect_uri="http://localhost:5000")

   token = oauth1.fetch_token('https://api.fyers.in/api/v1/genrateToken/',
   client_secret='app_secret',
   code='the_auth_code_returned')

Truly appreciate the help.

Comment: you should be using a `requests.Session()` to create a session and then using the session for get/post etc. to persist cookies across requests - are you doing this?

Comment: You should start by tracing a good login sequence using e.g. Telerik Fiddler - then see if you can reproduce the get/post/etc. and headers using your pythong code.

Comment: Yes, tried using the requests.Session, no luck with that. I also tried webbrowser.open(url). That seems to work fine, but then I need to capture the redirect url. Also, this won't be preferred method, as I'd like to completely be independent of browser opening/reading from browser as I want to deploy it on a linux server with no browser on a shared hosting environment.

Comment: "no luck with that" - the redirect URL *must* come from the server because the redirect to browser doesn't happen by magic - maybe you aren't looking hard enough. Ignore webbrowser.open for the moment - concentrate on tracing a login to reproduce using Python. You can tell requests not to follow redirects automatically (which can hide them from you) - so do that and then make your code replicate step by step the successful login sequence you traced.

Answer (score 0):

you are accessing only with Python...
you dont need to do anything manually in a browser..

This API not sure if what you wnat to.

I Believe you registred an APP , got your `app_secret`
the step

```
response = app_session.auth()
```

answer you with a `authorization_code`

```
"data" : {

"authorization_code": "eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJqaGdqZzg3NiQ3ODVidjVANjQ3NTZ2NSZnNyM2OTg3Njc5OHhkIjoiWElHVFVYVjBSSSIsImV4cCI6MTU2MTU5NzM5Ny41NjQxNTV9.Agl-Uus63NforrUEdbG7YUlPcbFXu9hLYm4akGuIBkU"
```

you may access that authorization token like that

```
import json 
r = json.dumps(reponse)
authorization_token = r['data']['authorization_code']
```

The authorization token AND you `app_id` must be passed as querystring to  `https://api.fyers.in/api/v1/genrateToken?`

the REAL user will be then asked to accept login trought your app
and if accepted , the user will be redirected to the URL *I imagined you inform in your app register.

let me know if it make sense

Comment: Hi, this is the api: https://api-docs.fyers.in/v1#authorization

Comment: ok, you are registering an APP to access the API ...  your teps are correct.
But now you need to redirect to your own application, and use the `access_token`  and `user_id` given (answered) to you in the last call.  Now your script can access the API in behaulf of that user

Comment: I edit my first answer, let me know if make any sense

Comment: I already have the https://api.fyers.in/api/v1/genrateToken? url, in fact that is the url that generate_token function creates. My problem is to be able to finish the login process without submitting this URL in a browser and copying the access token from the redirecrted url

Comment: thats why I comment "I'n not sure" if this API will work for you. This API if I understand it , is for a web app that you access the API in bahalf of a user ...   and for that, you need a browser to get the acceptance of that user.